# channel form date field customize

Tags: date, channel-form, date-format

How should I use third party date picker?
Because EE date field seem not user friendly.

1) If my date is to insert birth date, then it is hard to navigate thru years.
2) how should I take away time in EE date field,cause i just need the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use DropDate field type https://github.com/experience/dropdate.ee_addon/wiki, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dropdate

Comment: hi, the how to show it in channel form?

Comment: You can put this tag within Channel Form: `{field:drop_date_field_name}`